# Найти нужный элемент в numpy массиве

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть 2 одномерных numpy массива.
К примеру, это a1 и a2.
Их кол-во элементов одинаковое и каждый из элементов этих двух массивов соответствует(это не значит что они обязательно одинаковые, просто есть связь) друг другу. Т.е. 100й элемент массива a1 связан с 100м элементом массива a2, 101й и 101й тоже и так далее. Задача заключается в том, чтобы найдя элемент массива а1, найти соответствующий ему элемент в другом массиве.

Нужный мне элемент первого массива я нахожу следующим образом:

```
 indx  = np.where(a1 == max(a1))
#результатом будет, к примеру 120й элемент массива, как мне теперь, 
#имея эту информацию, обратиться именно к нужному элементу, если индекс постоянно будет меняться?
#Попробовал следующее, но безрезультатно (глупо)
indx2 = np.where(a2 == indx)
```

подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать

Comment: Есть метод `numpy.argwhere`, который как раз выдаст вам _индекс_ искомого элемента. С другой стороны, может, вам лучше задуматься об ином способе хранения данных. например, о словарях? или pandas Series?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае и  argmax подойдет.